# Select data (rows) of only last day of each month

Tags: pandas, datetime

I want to select only the rows which is the last day of each month. For ex:
The output of the following dataframe will be as below

```
date    Sales
0   2015-04-01  2416000
1   2015-04-02  2414000
2   2015-04-03  2416000
3   2015-04-04  2422000
4   2015-04-05  2434000
......

17  2015-05-18  2446000
18  2015-05-19  2454000
19  2015-05-20  2456000
20  2015-05-21  2453000
21  2015-05-22  2461000
```

Output:

```
 date        Sales
2015-04-05  2434000
2015-05-22  2461000
```

I have tried this:

```
df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby(df.date.to_period('M'))['index'].idxmax()]
```

But it gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try with `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.month,as_index=False).max()` , if the date col is not datetime dtype, convert it first using `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: With my original dataframe which has date from 2015- 2019 the output shows with only 2018 and 2019 data and also sales data is coming different not what is actually present in the row. Dont know why@anky_91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this looks `transform` with `boolean_indexing`:

```
df[df['date'].eq(df.groupby([df['date'].dt.year,
           df['date'].dt.month])['date'].transform('max'))]
```

---

```
         date      Sales
4  2015-04-05  2434000.0
21 2015-05-22  2461000.0
```